# stuck to call view model from view

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a tree view like below added mousedouble click

```
<TreeView 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Name="tvTopics"            
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        MouseDoubleClick="tvTopics_MouseDoubleClick"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TierOneItems}"
        SelectedItemChanged="treeView1_SelectedItemChanged">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Topic.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />        
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

on my code behind

```
 private void tvTopics_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;

        if (tv.SelectedItem is TopicTreeItemViewModel)
        {
           Model.SelectedTopic = ((TopicTreeItemViewModel)tv.SelectedItem).Topic;

        }
     }
```

here i am trying to pass my "topic" value to my view model but i have no idea how to pass or call my view model method.

```
    public class TopicTreeViewModel : NotificationObject, ITopicTreeViewModel
    {

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public TopicTreeViewModel(IGatewayService storyService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            this.storyService = storyService;
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            this.AddTopicCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.AddTopic);

            Helper.SubscriptionTokenList_LocationSearch.Add(this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<LocationSearchEvent>().Subscribe(OnLocationSearch, ThreadOption.UIThread));
            Helper.SubscriptionTokenList_SubjectSearch.Add(this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<SubjectSearchEvent>().Subscribe(OnSubjectSearch, ThreadOption.UIThread));

        }
        public void MouseDoubleClick(Topic topic)
        {
            if (topic != null && topic is Topic)
            {
                switch (this.searchType)
                {
                    case SearchType.Location:
                        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddLocationEvent>().Publish((Topic)topic);
                        break;
                    case SearchType.Subject:
                        this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<AddSubjectEvent>().Publish((Topic)topic);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And the interface connect between view and view model

```
 public interface ITopicTreeViewModel
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<TopicTreeItemViewModel> TierOneItems { get; }

    ICommand SearchCommand { get; }

    string SearchText { get; set; }

    Topic SelectedTopic { get; set; }
}
```

All im trying to do here is passing the topic value to my view model when the mousedouble click event triggered.

I have no idea how to pass or bind this value. any help much appreciated.

Comment: is that Model in Model.SelectedTopic a TopicTreeViewModel ? if it is then you can just call Model.MouseDoubleClick

Comment: Model.SelectedTopic is my interface of my TopicTreeViewModel,updated my OP with interface code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **Prism** and **MVVM** in particular, it is reccomended to add the minimal code behind implementation as possible. Therefore, every logic or action performed would be handled directly into the **ViewModel**.

Instead of handling the event on the View's *Code Behind*, you should bind the *MouseDoubleClick* event to a ***Delegate Command*** in the **ViewModel**. So, in order to achieve this, you would need to set the proper **ViewModel** as the **DataContext** of the **View**. This way, *Binding* would be resolved through the **DataContext** implementation.

The following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapter would be helpful to understand the interaction between **View** and **ViewModel**:

- [Implementing the MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [Advance MVVM scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

In addition, you could take a look at the **MVVM Prism QuickStart** and undestand how the *Binding* to the *View-ViewModel* interaction is implemented.

I hope this helped, Regards.